# Python should I use threading

Tags: python

I currently have a couple of small applications < 500 lines. I am intending to eventually run them on a small LINUX ARM box. Is it better to combine these applications and use threading, or continue to have them as two separate applications?

These applications plus a very small website use a small sqlite database, though only one of the applications write everything else currently does reads. Due to constraints of the target box I am using Python 2.6.

I am using SQLite to prevent data loss over several days of use. There is no direct interaction between the two application though there is the potential for database locking issue especially during period data maintenance. Stopping these issue are a concern also the foot print of the two applications as the target devices are pretty small.

Comment: Threading is heaps of trouble. Do you have a good reason for shared memory and concurrent execution, and do you have a clear idea of how you'd achieve thread safety? Otherwise I'd default to "Hell no!" ;)

Comment: @delnan And i will watching at you when you want write script for ping about 1000 computers for example =)

Comment: @Denis: Lots of independent, long-runnning IO sounds like a good reason for concurrency, and synchronization is a non-issue as (nearly) no state is shared. Sounds exactly like the kind of think I'd use threads of multiprocessing for ;)

Answer (score 4):

Depends on whether you need them to share data and how involved the sharing is. Other than that, from a speed point of view, for a multiprocessing machine, threading won't give you much of an advantage over separate processes.

If sharing can easily take place via a flat file or database then just let them be separate rather than complicating via threading.

Answer (score 2):

For performance purpose, I will suggest you to use threads, process consumes much more resources than threads, it will be faster to create and need less memory (usefull in embedded environment), but of course, you'll have to deal with the common traps of multithreading programmation (concurent access solved by locks, but locks may lead to interlocking...)

If you plan to use many libraries that make low level calls, maybe with C extension developped  that could not release properkly the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), in this case, processes can be a better solution, to allow your applications to run even when one is blocked by GIL.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass data between the two, you could use the Queues and other mechanisms in the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

It's often much simpler to use multiprocessing rather than sharing memory or objects using the threading module.

If you don't need to pass data between your programs, just run them separately (and release any locks on files or databases as soon as possible to reduce contention).

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to adopt a process rather than a threaded approach to resolving this issue. The primary factor in this decision is simplicity. The second factor is whilst one of these applications will be carrying out data acquisition the other will be communicating with a modem on an ad-hoc basis (receiving calls) I don't have control over the calling application but based on my  investigations, there is the potential for a lot to go wrong. 
There are a couple of factor which may change the approach further down the line primarily the need for the two processes to interact to prevent data contention on the database. Secondly if resources (memory/disk space/cpu) become an issue (due to the size of the device) one application should give me the ability to manage these problems. 
That said the data acquisition application is already threaded. This allows the parent thread to manage the worker when exceptions arise, as the device will not be in a managed environment.